# Error:Failed to resolve: support-vector-drawable

Tags: android, gradle

I have a problem with gradle. it was working fine but all of sudden when I was rebuilding the project it gives me this error:

> Error:Failed to resolve: support-vector-drawable

I can't find out what my problem is?

My `app.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:0.8.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.arizeh.arizeh"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 22
    multiDexEnabled true
    versionCode 29
    versionName "3.0.5"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    testInstrumentationRunner 
    buildTypes {
        release {
           minifyEnabled false
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
        targetCompatibility 1.8
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26+'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2'

    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.shawnlin:number-picker:2.4.2'
    compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:2.0@aar'
    compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:2.2@aar'

    compile 'com.zarinpal:purchase:0.0.3-beta'

    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Add `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` in defaultConfig

```
defaultConfig {
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
```

If an error still persists then

```
allprojects {
 repositories {
    google() // make it first element
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Where is that located in react native project? I am new to react .

Answer (score 34):

In my case, I've moved the Google repo on the top in the *build.gradle* config:

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
      google() // now here
      mavenLocal()
      jcenter()
      maven {
          // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
        url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
      }
      // google() // was here
  }
}
```

Comment: Moving `google()` to the first element in the list helped me as well.

Answer (score 9):

I just encountered this error along with some others:

```
Failed to resolve: support-vector-drawable
Failed to resolve: livedata-core
Failed to resolve: common
Failed to resolve: runtime
Failed to resolve: viewmodel
Failed to resolve: monitor
```

I'm not using React Native but found the answer on [there](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21907):

In `android/build.gradle` move the `jcenter()` to the bottom:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        }
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: ooh WOOOW WTF is wrong with android development? I can't just spend 8 hours on debugging gradle scripts on every android update -_-

Comment: @Tudor Yep, I am iOS mainly and coming back to Android is such a PITA.

Answer (score 8):

I faced this error on androidx project and solved it with:

1- in Build.gradle (Module file), android{} section add:

```
   vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
```

2- in dependencies {} section,

change :

```
 implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.1'
```

to update version:

```
 implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0-beta02'
```

compile again.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem. you must change build.gradle to

```
 // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem.
Resolved it via raising the version of v7 Support Libraries:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
```

Comment: tried the other solutions to no avail, this is what worked for me

Answer (score 2):

- i have tried enough and getting the same issue as in screen shot and finally got success.

[image]

my code was like this..

[image]

so after searching enough i solved it by adding maven in my gradle file..

[image]

its solved then..

Answer (score 1):

You should add this to build.gradle(module: app)

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
```

Comment: I have the same error and I am trying to do it for the last 3 hours. I did what you said,i tried moving google() to top, still cant figure it out . On github, react-bot has closed the issues without any answer. Please help

Answer (score 0):

I try many but only this decoration help me to sync the Gradle,
Hope this one help yours

```
 repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
```

And actually add this line to defaultConfig of app module :

```
vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
```