# Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath' in react native

Tags: android, react-native

I tried running react-native run-android after having set up React Native using react-native init as I hate expo. 
But, I am getting problem here as this:

```
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find support-vector-drawable.aar (com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1).
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-vector-drawable/27.1.1/support-vector-drawable-27.1.1.aar
> Could not find livedata-core.aar (android.arch.lifecycle:livedata-core:1.1.0).
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/android/arch/lifecycle/livedata-core/1.1.0/livedata-core-1.1.0.aar
> Could not find viewmodel.aar (android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.0).
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/android/arch/lifecycle/viewmodel/1.1.0/viewmodel-1.1.0.aar
> Could not find runtime.aar (android.arch.core:runtime:1.1.0).
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/android/arch/core/runtime/1.1.0/runtime-1.1.0.aar
```

Any idea on how to get this working? I tried every question possible, but none of them seems working!

Comment: Post your `build.gradle` and `app/build.gradle`

Comment: here is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51151050/8034839

Answer (score 5):

This worked! 
Just move google() from bottom to top in allprojects > repositories in build.gradle of module. 
Reference -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/52950717/8237551

Comment: @KyloRen, if you are using Android Gradle Plugin **below 3.0.0**, then should add `maven {
      url "https://maven.google.com"
    }` instead of `google()`

Comment: No i was using google 3+. It was my own stupidity, I was doing everything and not saving it. I saved and set environment variable and it worked

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to do the following

```
  cordova plugin add cordova-android-support-gradle-release --fetch
```

Remove cordova-plugin-add-swift-support from my plugins

used the versions mentioned here https://cordova.apache.org/news/2017/11/10/plugins-release.html

to remove cordova-plugin-compat

and finally move to the top

```
    maven {
      url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
```

or

```
    google()
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was set gradle folder expect `%user_profile%\.gradle` in android studio project setting and also I forgot to set `GRADLE_USER_HOME` to custom gradle folder.
Or you should set GRADLE_USER_HOME in Environment to custom folder or use default gradle folder that dose not need to GRADLE_USER_HOME

Answer (score 0):

Insure U have a proper internet connection and bandwidth. (+Probabley Proxy setting).