# ERROR: Failed to resolve: vectordrawable-animated

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, androidx

How to fix this problem in gradle ? I'm using androidx and I've checked this link "[Error:Failed to resolve: support-vector-drawable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50912739/errorfailed-to-resolve-support-vector-drawable)" before,
But I couldn't find a suitable answer according to my question.

Comment: Show some code where  you are having issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error:Failed to resolve: support-vector-drawable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50912739/errorfailed-to-resolve-support-vector-drawable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved : This solution is worked for me 
just replace 2 lines of code in this answer
"https://stackoverflow.com/a/50912781"
like this :
in build.gradle(app)

```
defaultConfig {
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
```

in build.gradle(project)

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' } // (now) make it first element
        google() 
        jcenter()
        // ... maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' } (was here before)
    }
}
```